# In Bash, how to write alias or function for "export GREP_COLOR='1;32'; grep --color"?

Tags: bash, grep

`grep` doesn't allow setting color by

```
grep --color='1;32'
```

(1 meaning bold, and 32 meaning green).  It has to use GREP_COLOR by

```
export GREP_COLOR='1;32'
```

and then use `grep --color`

**How do we alias or write a function for grep so that we have 2 versions of grep (say, grep and grepstrong)**, one for usual green font, and the other one, green font with a black (or white) background?

```
alias grep='export GREP_COLOR="1;32"; grep --color'
```

won't work because if we use

```
grep some_function_name | grep 3
```

then the above alias will generate results of the grep, and pipe into `export`, so the second grep won't get any input at all and just waiting there.

Comment: Note that `GREP_COLOR` is deprecated in favor of the more expressive `GREP_COLORS` variable (see http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Environment-Variables.html)

Comment: Adam: can it be set to highlight filenames as well?  Our Ruby on Rails project has really long pathnames and also our code can be more than 80 characters wide, so often it is hard to scan for filenames that easily.  Sometimes the matched content is not cared as much as the filenames.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With bash, you can set environment variables for just a single command by prepending the command with "key=value" pairs:

```
GREP_COLOR='1;32' grep --color <whatever>
```

Example:

```
echo foo | VAR=value bash -c 'read line; echo $VAR: $line'
```

So in your case, just say:

```
alias grep='GREP_COLOR="1;32" grep --color'
```

Comment: also note: need to escape the grep for grepstrong -- otherwise invoking grep will also invoke that color as well.  See the lines in my answer on this page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting this in your .bashrc file? Just do it like this:

```
export GREP_COLOR="1;32"
alias grep='grep --color'
```

and you should be good to go

Comment: for 2 versions of grep... is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Using Sean's answer, the alias for `grepstrong` needs to escape grep, so that it won't invoke the grep using the green font color.

```
alias grep='GREP_COLOR="1;32" grep --color'
alias grepstrong='GREP_COLOR="1;34;46" \grep --color'
```